# not able to clean install windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, installation, product-key

i want to clean install win 8 on my new lenovo, i have heard that OEM key is stored in the bios and is automatically applied on a clean install. i have downloaded windows 8 file from internet- en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso .

i tried installing windows, when i click on "install now" , it automatically shows the message- **"the product key entered does not match any of the windows images available for installation,enter a different product key"**. when i click "ok", it goes back to the initial start screen where there is an option to either install or repair windows 8.

i have no idea what is the problem here , the product key should have been automatically applied, but here it is showing the error message. do i need to ask for a DVD from lenovo?

Comment: Re-insall windows. Don't know why but that works.

Comment: @chipperyman573 That's what he's trying to do...

Comment: No, install it again. It will count as an upgrade.

Comment: @chipperyman573 That doesn't work with Windows 8, that only worked with the Windows 7 upgrade.

Comment: Really? That's how I did it.

Comment: @chipperyman573 The Windows 8 disk will not let you install without a valid key, unlike the Windows 7 disk. You could install full Windows 7 without a key from the upgrade disk, and then upgrade the unactivated copy of windows with the Windows 7 upgrade key. Windows 8 requires a valid key to install it at all, which is the problem the OP is having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an OEM system/key, then you need an OEM installation disk I believe. I know for pre-Windows 8, these disks were usually different than the retail disks that you bought in the store.

You should be able to get such a disk from Lenovo, or acquire it from any other source as long as you verify the SHA1 hash of the file. It looks like the following disk image should work for any Windows 8 key, retail or OEM:

```
Filename: en_windows_8_x64_dvd_915440.iso
SHA1: 1CE53AD5F60419CF04A715CF3233F247E48BEEC4
```

You can get it from MSDN if you have access, or through alternative means-- Just make sure to [double-check the SHA1 hash](http://www.howtogeek.com/67241/) so that you know the disk image has not been tampered with.

<sub>Just noticed that this *is* the disk image you have. Leaving answer here for anyone else that runs into the problem that the answer applies to.</sub>

Comment: i have the same disk, but it is showing the error message.

Comment: the iso image has the same SHA1.

i tried a different method , i created a ei.cfg file in the sources folder of the DVD with the following contents,
[EditionID]
Core
[Channel]
Retail
[VL]
0
now it goes till the screen where we can choose the partition to install windows and format it, but when i choose a partition, it displays an error message,
"windows cannot be installed on this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style."

but this error should not have been displayed as windows 8 requires GPT partition, and i have the same.
do you  think there is some error in the ei.cfg file ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install windows 7 in your machine? Commonly partitions created with windows 7 shows these types of errors while installing windows 8.Do a complete format your entire hard disk and install the os

Comment: no , my current windows is windows 8, but still it is showing that error. also, i am not able to boot from efi usb device when i am in the UEFI mode in the bios, but when it is in "legacy support" , i can boot from usb.